# How to make this script run in the background and listen for a "copy" action?

Tags: python

The script below does is if I copy a link like this: `http://urlshortener.io/s/1234rIHs/?s=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome_content%2F`, it will change to
`example.com/some_content/` if I clicked the button.

Is there a way that when I run this script then it will listen in the background for a "copy" action, and then if I copy some text in my browser, it will automatically slice the text I just copied and I won't need to click the button?

Right now, I still have to click the button in order for the slicing to happen.

```
from tkinter import *
from urllib import parse
from tkinter import Tk


root = Tk()
root.title("Slicer")

root.geometry('304x70')

lbl = Label(root, text="Link")
lbl.pack()



def clicked():
    clip = root.clipboard_get()
    clip = parse.unquote(clip)[45:]

    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(clip)
    lbl.configure(text= clip)

btn = Button(root, text="Slice", command=clicked, height = 3, width = 40)
btn.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have a look at Bryan Oakleys answer to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184570/clipboard-detector-in-python).

Comment: @yalpsid, hi, did my answer solve your issue. If so, please consider accepting and/or upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip). Run an infinite loop, keep detecting for urls in the loop, modify when found.

```
import pyperclip, time

# Modify is_url and modify_url, according to your need
def is_url(s):
    return True

def modify_url(url_string):
    return "Hello World"

while True:
    on_clip = pyperclip.paste()
    if is_url(on_clip):
        pyperclip.copy(modify_url(on_clip))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```